# Can you create SQL database transactions, and run things outside of those transactions while the transaction is opened?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I am sort of a newbie when it comes to transactions in databases, so don't have much experience with them. I am in the situation where I have a `jobs` table, which is a job queue, and I want to process the job. Ideally I prevent other processes from accessing a particular actively-worked-on job record, and then delete the job after it is completely handled.

The problem is, some jobs will be fully in a single transaction from start to finish, while other jobs have parts which don't need to be wrapped in a transaction. For example, say we are querying for some `tags` in the middle of a transaction while we are going to increment the tag usage count for a particular user (just making this up), to increase their stats. In theory, I think, I would want to do this (pseudocode):

```
begin transaction
tag_update_job = select * from jobs where id = x
tag_ids = select ids from tags where name in tag_update_job.tag_names
increment count for user_tag_counts_rollup for each tag_ids
delete job
commit transaction
```

But what I'd actually like to do is not have that `select ids from tags` in the transaction, since it doesn't need to be in the transaction, but it requires some transaction data as input to the query. I am using [knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) as a SQL wrapper, for PostgreSQL, and am not sure if it's possible in plain SQL to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish: have everything be in the transaction, except fetching the tags, even though it occurs in the middle of the transaction.

How can that be accomplished? Or what should I do?

Comment: The first three steps can be done in a single UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1):

The query does not modify anything, so there is no benefit in keeping it outside the transaction. You might just as well have it be a part of the transaction, because it does not take any unpleasant locks on anything. I am not sure what you are trying to optimize here, but my advice is to leave it well alone.

What you should optimize, however, are the first two queries: that should be a single query with a join.